# Update same table N records using group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I am using Mysql Database and I have time slot table in that different time slots for particular date based on permitted count (N) records should be updated to valid.

```
CREATE  TABLE tmpSlots(
    SlotID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY  ,
    StartSlot DATETIME,
    EndSlot DATETIME,
    Valid BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0
);  
insert into tmpSlots VALUES(1,'2020-08-01 08:30:00', '2020-08-01 09:10:00',0 );
insert into tmpSlots VALUES(2,'2020-08-01 09:30:00', '2020-08-01 10:10:00',0 );
insert into tmpSlots values(3,'2020-08-01 10:30:00', '2020-08-01 11:10:00',0 );
insert into tmpSlots values(4,'2020-08-01 12:30:00', '2020-08-01 13:10:00',0 );
insert into tmpSlots values(5,'2020-08-07 08:30:00', '2020-08-07 09:10:00',0 );
insert into tmpSlots values(6,'2020-08-07 09:30:00', '2020-08-07 10:10:00',0 );
insert into tmpSlots values(7,'2020-08-07 10:30:00', '2020-08-07 11:10:00',0 );
insert into tmpSlots values(8,'2020-08-07 12:30:00', '2020-08-07 13:10:00',0 );

DECLARE permitcount INT ; 
SET permitcount =2;
```

As permitcount so only 2 slots are allowed per day  first 2 records should be updated to valid =true
Expected result
[image]

```
UPDATE tmpSlots t1 SET valid=1
FROM  (
  ...........
.
   GROUP  BY Date(StartSlot)
   ) AS sq
WHERE
```

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: edited i am using mysql database @Gordon Linoff

Comment: what if startTime and endTime are in different dates?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join` in an `update`.  However, you don't want aggregation.  Instead, you can use `row_number()` to enumerate the values on each day.  Then, select the first two per day using a `where` clause:

```
update tmpslots s join
       (select s2.*,
               row_number() over (partition by date(startslot) order by startslot) as seqnum
        from tmpslots s2
       ) s2
       on s2.slotid = s.slotid
    set s.value = 1
    where s2.seqnum <= 2;
```

This assigns the date based on the `startslot`.

In earlier versions, I would just use two updates:

```
update tmpslots s join
       (select date(startslot) as dte, min(slotid) as min_slotid
        from tmpslots s2
        group by dte
       ) s2
       on s2.min_slotid = s.slotid
    set s.value = 1;

update tmpslots s join
       (select date(startslot) as dte, min(slotid) as min_slotid
        from tmpslots s2
        where s.value = 0
        group by dte
       ) s2
       on s2.min_slotid = s.slotid
    set s.value = 1;
```

Although you could finagle this into a single update, two updates seem simpler.

Comment: @Gorden Linoff i am using 5.6 version of mysql which not supports row_number() over is either is any alternate way for below version 8 my sql